# Inner join between pandas dataframes does not work with comparing DenseVector types

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, inner-join

I am working with pandas dataframes and I want to get the coincidences between 2 dataframes, df1 and df2.

df1:

```
+------------+-------+
| features   | col2  |
+------------+-------+
| [1.0, 2.0] |   2   |
+------------+-------+
| [1.0, 3.0] |   1   |
+------------+-------+
```

df2:

```
+------------+-------+
| features   | col2  |
+------------+-------+
| [1.0, 2.0] |   2   |
+------------+-------+
| [1.0, 4.0] |   5   |
+------------+-------+
```

Column 'features' is of type DenseVector.

One of the columns (named 'features') of both dataframes are of type DenseVector. I have the next code:

```
s1 = pandas.merge(df1, df2, how='inner', on=['features'])
```

I checked that both dataframes have a DenseVector element with the same values. For example: DenseVector([1.0, 2.0, 3.0]). But no coincidences are captured by s1.

If I check the next code in which the DenseVector element of df1 is in df2, I get False when I should get True:

```
df1.features[0] in df2.features
```

If I apply the next code, I get True, because it compares all the elements of the vector:

```
df1.features[0].all() in df2.features.all()
```

How can I apply the inner join in order to get the vectors that coincide?

Comment: Can you provide some example data for `df1` and `df2`? It's difficult to understand what's going on without any.

Comment: I edited the question with an example.

Comment: Same problem if it is string type. The comparison gives false.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure we can use the list field as a key to merge, however below is a workaround for your questions:

```
import pandas as pd 

d1 = {'features': [[1.0,2.0], [1.0,3.0]],
     'col2': [2,1]}

d2 = {'features': [[1.0,2.0], [1.0,4.0]],
     'col2': [2,5]}    

df1 = pd.DataFrame(d1)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(d2)

df1['features1'] = df1['features'][0]
df1['features2'] = df1['features'][1]
df2['features1'] = df2['features'][0]
df2['features2'] = df2['features'][1]

mdf = pd.merge(df1,df2,on=['features1', 'features2'], suffixes = ('_df1', '_df2'))

print(mdf)
```